# Is $SL_2(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})$ generated by the elementary matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

By the elementary matrices I mean the matrices with diagonal elements $1$ and at most one nonzero element off-diagonal. I have seen it claimed that this is true, but no proof was given. I know that the results holds for matrices over an euclidean ring, but $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ is not even an integral domain (for general $n$.) So how can we demonstrate this result not using that $SL_2(Z)\rightarrow SL_2(Z/nZ)$ is surjective?

Comment: As you mention, this is true for $\operatorname{SL}_2(Z)$ since $Z$ is Euclidean. Now just take everything mod $n$.

Comment: Is every element of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$ the image of one in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$, @Dane?

Answer (score 2):

The reduction map $\operatorname{SL}_2(Z) \to \operatorname{SL}_2(Z/nZ)$ is surjective.
For a proof of this fact, see for example Theorem 3.2 of these [notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/SL%282,Z%29.pdf) by Keith Conrad.

What you want to prove now follows from the same fact about $\operatorname{SL}_2(Z)$ by reducing modulo $n$.

Comment: I actually want to prove this fact using my question

Comment: But the proof in Conrad's notes is so short and elementary that there does not seem to be much point in trying to do it a different way.

Comment: I agree but the proof is not an elegant one.